# Accessing key value pairs from ajax call with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using jquery to call for a Json object from the server. This is my call:

```
$.getJSON( url, function( data ) {...}
```

I am getting back (from console.log) the following object:

```
> 0: Object
   cable key: "1"
   cable type: "Building Wire..."
> 1: Object
   cable key: "2"
   cable type: "PVC Wire..."
...
```

I am trying to access both key and value like the examples below without any luck.

```
$.getJSON( url, function( data ) {

    $.each( data, function( key,  value ) {

         $( "#CableType" ).append( $( "<option value='" + value['cable key'] + "'>" + value['cable type'] + "</option>" ) );

    });
})
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: It is working fine. http://jsfiddle.net/8wdzqpc1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to get a property of the VALUE instead of the object. Use

```
data['cable key']
```

instead of

```
value['cable key']
```

Beside, adding elements to the DOM inside a loop is inefficient. You need to collect your html in a string, and after the loop ends, put it in the DOM. You can do something like this:

```
$.getJSON( url, function(data){
    var htmlCollection = "",
        propertyName;

    data.forEach(function(pair){            
        htmlCollection += "<option value='" + pair['cable key'] + "'>" + pair['cable type'] + "</option>";
    });

    $( "#CableType" ).append(htmlCollection);
});
```

Comment: Hi @Yair Tavor, when I try your method (data['varname']) I get undefined.

Comment: have you tried it using the for-in loop instead of the $.each function?

Comment: AH, I changed it to "data.forEach(function(d) {" loop and I can now access the values via "d.cable_type". Thanks!

Comment: of course! silly me, data in an array not an object. I fixed the code example.